# MongoDB index use on mongoose aggregate() call

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following `aggregate()` call in Mongoose 6.9.0:

```
const latestTradeForPair = await Trade.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: 'tradablepairs',
         localField: 'tradablePair',
         foreignField: '_id',
         as: 'tradablePairDetails',
      },
   },
   {
      $match: {
         'tradablePairDetails.pair_name': pairName,
      },
   },
   {
      $sort: {
         time: -1,
      },
   },
   {
      $limit: 1,
   },
]);
```

I have been trying, unsuccessfully, to create an index to speed up this query, since I have millions of the `Trade` documents. I have this:

```
tradeSchema.index({ tradablePair: 1, time: -1 });
```

However, the query does not appear to be hitting this index (according to Compass). I have been quizzing ChatGPT about this, but he/she is not very helpful and every suggestion gives rise to errors about writeConcerns and other such things.

How do I create an index that will be targeted by this query?

Comment: Move the $sort to be the first stage of the pipeline and make sure you have a single field index of { time: 1} on the base Trade collection

Comment: Another thought: is the pairName match selective? If so it might be better to go in the opposite direction (eg start with tradablepairs and $lookup to the other collection)

Comment: @user20042973 First stage of the pipeline…how? You mean, sort all of the trades before performing the $lookup ‘join’? Gotta be honest, ChatGPT generated that query, are those nests necessary?

Comment: Nests? Perhaps it would be better to start with examples of your schema (with sample docs) and a description/sample of what you are trying to logically retrieve with your query